# Always encrypted mapping in NHibernate

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate, always-encrypted

Currently I'm using **SQL Server 2016** to make benefit of `Always Encrypted` feature. There are a couple of columns that I should encrypt. I've encrypted those columns with SQL Server. `NHibernate` can easily read data from `SQL Server` but when it tries to insert data in the DB it will throw an exeption like below:

> Operand type clash: nvarchar(4000) encrypted with (encryption_type =
>   'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name =
>   'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name =
>   'CEK_Auto1', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'EncTest') is
>   incompatible with nvarchar(250) encrypted with (encryption_type =
>   'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name =
>   'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name =
>   'CEK_Auto1', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'EncTest')

This is my column mapping for the specific column in `NHibernate`:

```
<column name="DisableTxt" length="100" sql-type="NVarChar" />
```

What mapping I should define in my `hbm` files?

Comment: Doesn't the exception suggest that there's a column datatype mismatch? What's the datatype and length of the underlying column?

Comment: @DavidOsborne thanks, I found a solution and write it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem, first I would like to describe why `NHibernate` can't work with `Encrypted Columns` in `Always Encrypted` feature:

When we enable `AlwaysEncrypted` in our connection string ,`ADO.NET` automatically executes a [store procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-describe-parameter-encryption-transact-sql) `sp_describe_parameter_encryption` before any db operations to to determine which parameters correspond to database columns that are protected by using the Always Encrypted feature. This sp is sensitive for the length of the fields and if the specified parameter length isn't equal to the column length, SQL Server will give us error below:

> Operand type clash: nvarchar(4000) encrypted with (encryption_type =
>   'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name =
>   'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name =
>   'CEK_Auto1', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'EncTest') is
>   incompatible with nvarchar(250) encrypted with (encryption_type =
>   'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name =
>   'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name =
>   'CEK_Auto1', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'EncTest')

This happens because `NHibernate` always define parameter size of `4000` for `NVarchar` columns (if column length isn't `NVarchar(max)`). So Imagine We've got a column with length of `30` but `NHibernate` define a parameter with the length of `4000` for specified column. Why `NHibernate` does that?

if you take a look on `SqlClientDriver.cs` line [146](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Driver/SqlClientDriver.cs) on `Nhibernate` source, you will see comment below:

> // Do not override the default length for string using data from
>   SqlType, since LIKE expressions needs
>   // larger columns.
>   https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3036

So how we can solve this problem? We can create a new `Driver` for `NHibernate` which define accurate parameter length. (of course if you don't care about `%%` like expressions). (I've used this method on `NHiberate 3.x`)

```
public class NewDriver : NHibernate.Driver.Sql2008ClientDriver
{
        public override IDbCommand GenerateCommand(CommandType type, SqlString sqlString, SqlType[] parameterTypes)
        {
            IDbCommand command = base.GenerateCommand(type, sqlString, parameterTypes);
            NewDirver.SetParameterSizes(command.Parameters, parameterTypes);
            return command;
        }

        public static void SetParamterSizes(IDataParameterCollection parameters, SqlType[] parameterTypes)
        {
            for(int index=0;index<parameters.Count;++index)
            {
                NewDriver.SetVariableLengthParameterSize((IDbDataParameter)parameters[index], parameterTypes[index]);
            }
        }

        public static void SetVariableLengthParmaeterSize(IDbDataParameter dbParam, SqlType sqlType)
        {
            SqlClientDriver.SetDefaultParameterSize(dbParam, sqlType);
            if(sqlType.LengthDefined && !IsText(dbParam, sqlType) && !IsBlob(dbParam, sqlType))
            {
                dbParam.Size = sqlType.Length;
            }

            if(sqlType.PrecesionsDefined)
            {
                dbParam.Precision = sqlType.Precision;
                dbParam.Scale = sqlType.Scale;
            }
        }


}
```

Comment: Why did you revert my edits. Your original code is full of typos and doesn't work. For example, The class is called "NewDriver" but later on when you reference its static methods you refer to it as NewDirver. You also called the static method "SetParamterSizes" yet when you call it you write SetParameterSizes. Same for the method "SetVariableLengthParmaeterSize". As it stands your code is broken. I fixed it in edit 2 but strangely you seem to prefer non functional code so you apparently reverted the edit.